# Distribution of objects in an activity

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity

I am performing correction on some screens, and on the screen I'm working now, there was a difficulty.

I have a few fields on screen, and even trying to relate the button with the bottom of the screen, the button is in the center.

And it is a large white part after button. I do not know what I can do to fix it. Note: I created the LinearLayout to try solucinar the problem and positions them.

[image]

My Code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinLayoutSpin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_TamPet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:entries="@array/tamPet_array"
            android:prompt="@string/tamPet_prompt"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/char_SobreVoce"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="8"
            android:minLines="6"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/spinner_TamPet"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_below="@id/LinLayoutSpin">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCadastraCliente"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sou um DoggieWalker"
            android:layout_below="@id/char_SobreVoce"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_background" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The new print after first comment. The white part is up and the form down.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set android:fillViewPort = "true" in your ScrollView.

In the second LinerLayout set android:layout_height="wrap_content"

you can optimize your screen layout by removing these LinerLayout, only need one RelativeLayout for this screen

Answer (score 0):

Set layout_gravity to bottom for the relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#ff000000">
```

Comment: No. the way you spoke, is the opposite. The white part is up and the form down.